# API that provides curated and geo-targeted images

Tags: images, api, geo-location

I am trying to find a service that can consume an IP, city, or state and return the URL of a curated image suitable to be used for a website background.

By suitable I suppose what I mean is that it is offered in high resolution, consistent in dimensions, and is likely a professionally taken photograph. Basically, stock images on demand.

The use case would be to assist in providing some subtle geo-targeting for users of a website. I have seen this on Chase Bank's website as an example.

Paid services are completely on the table for this. If they can take the work and cost out of building an image library then I'm happy to pay them for that.

Comment: As we don't recommend services here, please focus your question on the API part. For what programming language should it be? If your goal is rather to find material for building your own collection, our sister-site [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better place.

Comment: Understandable. Thank you moving the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try Google Street view , it will give you Pics, (If some one have added pics to that location. and selecting the best is still the logic that you need to implement) 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/
or this may help

Also , View this link , it may help out
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14798/open-source-alternatives-to-googles-streetview-engine

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I think I'll end up having to build out the image/location myself.